# How to get the clicked element src with javascript

Tags: javascript, src, stock

I need stock the video src when i click in a var

```
<a onclick="hide(this)">
     <div id="preview">
            <div id="preview-coverflow"> 
                <video width="100%" height="100%"  class="cover" loop data-name="For Wes" autoplay>
                    <source src="vid/mp4/For_Wes.mp4" type="video/mp4">stock
                </video>
           </div>
     </div>
</a>
```

Comment: `i click in a var`? Variable?

Comment: yes a variable i tried so much thing and i alway have a undefined src

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't see how `hide` was defined, you can either add it to the bottom of the page, or make it a global variable by adding `window` to the front ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/r2Ls60pf/2/)):

```
window.hide = function() {
  var target = document.querySelector('#preview');
  // toggle display
  target.style.display = target.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

Most developers would recommend that you separate from from function. In that case, remove the `onclick` from the link and add this code to the bottom ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/r2Ls60pf/3/)):

```
// change HTML to <a class="toggle">
document.querySelector('.toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var target = document.querySelector('#preview');
  // toggle display
  target.style.display = target.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
});
```